How to prove this "cofinite topology with a distinguished point" is T3.5?
In Ryszard Engelking's General Topology, its Example 1.1.8 defines a topology as follows:

Let $X$ be an arbitrary infinite set, $x_0$ a point in $X$ and $\mathcal{O}$ the family consisting of all subsets of $X$ that do not contain $x_0$ and of all cofinite subsets of $X$. One verifies readily that $(X,\mathcal{O})$ is a topological space.

The arthor after in Section 1.5 says that

In Example 1.4.4 and 1.4.5 we proved that the Sorgenfrey line and the Niemytzki plane are Tychonoff space; all spaces defined in Section 1.1.1 are Tychonoff spaces as well.

But it seems not very obvious that the space defined above is $T_{3\frac12}$. One result in Example 1.4.6 may be useful:

We shall show that for every continuous function $f\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$ there exists a countable $F_\sigma$ set $X_0\subseteq X$ such that $f(x)=f(x_0)$ for every $x\in X\setminus X_0$.
The set $X_i=X\setminus f^{-1}((f(x_0)-1/i,f(x_0)+1/i))$ is closed and does not contain $x_0$; thus it's finite. One can readily verify the set $X_0=\bigcup X_i$ has the required property.

Can anybody give help? Or maybe it's not true?

I don’t know exactly your definition of $T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$ space, which means for me Hausdorff and completely regular, namely each pair of closed set and point can be separated.
In our case we have:
Hausdorff:  Let $x,y\in X$,$x\neq y$ and  $x,y\neq x_0$. Then $\{x\}$ and $\{y\}$ are two disjoint open neighbourhoods of $x$ and $y$ respectively. Instead, if $y=x_0$, then $\{x\}$ and $X\setminus\{x\}$ are two disjoint opens neighborhoods of $x$ and $y$ respectively.
Completely regular space: Let $x\neq x_0$ and $C$ be a closed set of $X$ not containing $x$. We define the map $f\colon X\to [0,1]$ sending each $y$ to $0$, if $y\neq x$, and $1$ otherwise.
This function is continuos since for each closed set $K$ of $[0,1]$ we have that
$$f^{-1}(K)=X\setminus \{x\}$$
if $K$ does not contain $1$, and
$$f^{-1}(K)=X$$
otherwise.
In both cases we have a closed set of $X$, so that $f$ is continuos.
Indeed, since  $x\neq x_0$, then $X\setminus \{x\}$ contains $x_0$, and so it is closed.
What about if the point $x=x_0$? We need to define $f$ as follows: $f(x)=0$ if $x\in C$, and $0$ otherwise.
In this case, given a closed set
$K$, if $K$ does not contain $1$, then the inverse image is either empty (so closed) or it is $C$, which is closed.
Instead, if $K$ contains $1$, then the inverse image of $K$ contains $x_0$, and so it has to be closed by definition of the topology of $X$.

There are some typo but I understand. Thanks!

Please, tell me, which typo :)
